# how to pass $task variable to blade file in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have following blade file as form.blade.php 

`action="{{ route('projects.files', ['project'=> $project->id, 'task'=>$task->id])}}">`

and My controller methods for saving is
```

```
private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$task){ 
    $file = new File;
    $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
    $file->project_id = $id;
    $file->task_id = $task;
    $file->save();
}
```

and My route is this

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/files', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but I got this error code here

```
Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\Jone\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

Comment: Your passing parameter 3 and receive parameter 4 so that `$task` id undefined

Comment: so how can fix it I have no an idea?

Comment: any body have an idea to solve this problem?